# How to select the two digit word from LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

```
.NET Framework
3D Studio Max
3d
3D Modeling
3G
3D Visualization
3D Rendering
1031 Exchanges
2G
AB
BC
CD
```

I want to extract the word by size of text like 3D, 3G, 2G, AB, BC CD, csv file in Libreoffice.

Comment: can you edit the question by adding a sample csv file and desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if any options in `libreoffice` would allow you to perform that action. But the following program would extract the two character words from the csv source file and will save in a result csv file.

You have to edit the source file path and destination file path as per your source file and desired destination file location. Also the source file contains the raw data.

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/home/bond/source.csv";
for p in `cat "$path"`;
do
word=`echo -n $p | wc -m`;
if [[ $word -eq 2 ]];
then
echo "$p" >> /home/bond/result.csv
else
exec &> /dev/null
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the CSV file in LibreOffice Calc and go to *Edit -> Find and Replace*.  Find: `\b(..)?\b.*` and Replace: `$1`.  Be sure that *Regular expressions* is checked.

Then press *Replace All*.

[image: find and replace]

Comment: I don't want to replace I want to see and and some of the change.

Comment: Then use `Find Next` and `Replace`.  Please edit the question to describe the desired result more specifically, as your comment is not very clear.